# railsで出力されるhtmlに余分なtext

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html

勝手に表記される無駄なtextを削除したいです。

railsで開発していたのですが、
一切表記していないのに以下のtextがweb上に書き出されます。

```
[#<Post id: 2, title: "second", body: "2bannme", 
created_at: "2017-04-15 21:51:00", 
updated_at: "2017-04-15 21:51:00">, 
#<Post id: 1, title: "firsrt time!!", body: "my dairy ", 
created_at: "2017-04-14 22:22:59", 
updated_at: "2017-04-14 22:22:59">]
```

これに対して適応されるindex.html.erbファイルはこちらです

```
<%= @posts.each do |post| %>
<div class="post_wrapper">
<h2 class= "title" ><%= link_to post.title, post %></h2>
<p class = "date" ><%= post.created_at.strftime("%B %d, %Y") %></p>
</div>
<% end %>
```

application.html.erbにはyieldタグしか特に書いてません。

初心者なので、伝わるか分かりませんがもし足りない情報などがあれば教えてください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<%= @posts.each do |post| %>`
の `=` が不要です。